# Identificar usuário pelo login

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, xhtml, spring-security

Olá, pessoal. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que mexe com cadastro de usuários e estou com o seguinte problema: no sistema existirão 3 tipos de usuários: Administrador, Normal e Temporário.

Dependendo do tipo de usuário, as áreas que ele conseguirá acessar e dados que conseguirá consultar devem ser alterados. Por exemplo, o usuário Administrador consegue ter acesso à tela de consulta e pode consultar todos os cadastros presentes no sistema, mas o usuário Normal só pode ver os dados do próprio cadastro.

No momento o meu primeiro problema é sobre a tela inicial (Home) depois que o usuário realiza o login. Nesta tela existe uma barra de ferramentas e dependendo do tipo de usuário, as opções que aparecem devem ser alteradas. Mas eu não estou conseguindo montar o código. O meu objetivo é que o sistema precisa retornar o tipo de usuário quando ele faz login para alterar as opções que aparecem na Home.

No meu banco de dados existe a tabela "usuario", onde são guardados os dados básicos como nome, telefone, email, etc..., a tabela "grupo", onde são definidos os grupos de usuários (no caso deste sistema, existirão 3 grupos nesta tabela: Administrador, normal e temporário) e a tabela "usuario_grupo" onde são associados os registros de "usuario" e "grupo".

Estou postando os códigos referentes às tela de login e Home.

Na parte de banco de dados, estou usando o PostGreSQL e hibernate.

Na parte de autenticação e autorização, estou usando o Spring Security

**Home.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Dashboard</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{gadoBean.inicializar}" type="preRenderView"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p:panel
        style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:450px;width:480px;border: none !important;">
        <p:panelGrid id="grid2" columns="2" styleClass="semBorda">
            <p:inputText id="pesquisarGado" size="50" style="height:25px;"
                value="#{pesquisaGadoBean.filtro.gadoId}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Digite o código do gado" />
            <p:button  outcome="/gado/rastrearGado" size="60" icon="ui-icon-search" update="grid2">
                <f:param name="gado" value="#{gado.gadoId}" />
            </p:button>
            <p:message for="pesquisarGado" display="icon" />

        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</ui:define>
```

**Login.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="sistema.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="Dummy" />
    <f:event listener="#{loginBean.preRender}" type="preRenderView">    </f:event>
</f:metadata>
<div id="login-dialog">
    <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    <h:form id="frm" prependId="false">

        <p:panel
             styleClass="grid-login">

            <p:graphicImage library="images" name="Rastrbov.png" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Nome *" style="font-weight:bold;" />
                <p:inputText size="18" id="j_username" value="#{loginBean.nome}"
                    a:placeholder="&#128273;Usuario" />
                <h:outputText value="Senha *" style="font-weight:bold;" />
                <p:password size="18" id="j_password"
                    a:placeholder="&#128273;Senha" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" width="100%" style="text-align:center">

                    <p:commandButton value="Entrar" action="#{loginBean.login}"
                        ajax="false" styleClass="botaoLogin" icon="ui-icon-circle-arrow-e"/>


                    <p:button value="Voltar" outcome="/Main.xhtml"
                        ajax="false" styleClass="botaoLogin" icon="ui-icon-home"/>
                    <br />


            </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid column="4" width="100%" style="text-align:center">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <p:commandLink style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;"
                                value="Cadastre-se"
                                onclick="PF('varDialogCadastrarUsuario').show()" type="button" />
                            <br />
                            <p:commandLink style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;"
                                value="Esqueci a senha"
                                onclick="PF('varDialogResetarSenha').show()" type="button" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>


        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <h:form>

        <p:dialog id="dialogResetarSenha" header="Recuperar Senha"
            widgetVar="varDialogResetarSenha" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
            resizable="false" hideEffect="fade">
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">

                <p:inputText value="#{usuarioLogadoMB.email}" required="true"
                    size="60" requiredMessage="O email é obrigatório"
                    id="emailRecuperaSenha" />
                <p:watermark value="Digite seu email" for="emailRecuperaSenha" />
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Enviar senha" icon="ui-icon-circle-check"
                actionListener="#{usuarioLogadoMB.solicitarNovaSenha}"
                oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed){varDialogResetarSenha.hide()}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button"
                icon="ui-icon-circle-close" onclick="varDialogResetarSenha.hide()" />

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
    <h:form>

        <p:dialog id="dialogCadastrarUsuario" header="Cadastrar Usuario"
            widgetVar="varDialogCadastrarUsuario" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
            resizable="false" hideEffect="fade">
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">

                <p:inputText id="nome" size="60"
                    value="#{cadastroUsuarioTempBean.usuarioTemp.nome}" />
                <p:watermark value="Digite seu nome" for="nome" />



                <p:inputText id="email" size="60"
                    value="#{cadastroUsuarioTempBean.usuarioTemp.email}" />
                <p:watermark value="Digite seu email" for="email" />

                <p:password id="senha" size="60"
                    value="#{cadastroUsuarioTempBean.usuarioTemp.senha}" />
                <p:watermark value="Digite sua senha" for="senha" />

            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton value="Confirmar" icon="ui-icon-circle-check"
                actionListener="#{cadastroUsuarioTempBean.salvar}"
                oncomplete="PF('varDialogCadastrarUsuario').hide()" />

            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button"
                icon="ui-icon-circle-close"
                onclick="PF('varDialogCadastrarUsuario').hide()" />

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

**LoginBean.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private FacesContext facesContext;

@Inject
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Inject
private HttpServletResponse response;

private String nome;


public void login() throws ServletException, IOException{
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
public void preRender(){
    if("true".equals(request.getParameter("invalid"))){
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Usuário ou senha invalido!");
    }
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
}
```

Pode ser que eu esteja esquecendo de algum arquivo. Pela parte do hibernate ou algum arquivo que esteja sendo importado nos códigos que postei.
Se for o caso, por favor me avisem que logo postarei o código correspondente.

Agradeço por qualquer sugestão ou conselho

Comment: A sua `home.xhtml` não contem o código do arquivo pai, então não é possivel verificar o código onde você tenta criar o menu. Talvez você consiga utilizar um `rendered` no `p:submenu` ou no `p:menuitem`, utilizando uma função no back end que verificaria se o usuário logado contem a role necessária para visualizar aquele item.

Comment: Certo, mas neste caso, você teria alguma sugestão sobre como resolver esta situação? Porque na verdade, os itens devem ser disponibilizados quando o usuário efetua o login e não quando ele coloca o cursor do mouse sobre os itens do menu. Ou seja, na minha opinião, acredito que devo colocar alguma função de verificação quando o usuário clicar no botão de login